# Powershell functions executed regardless of being called

Tags: function, powershell

I'm having trouble understanding how Powershell treats functions. In the following script all functions are called, even if I never actually call the main function. Does powershell not have a concept of call chain?

```
param([string]$directory)

[string]$global:sqlscript;
$global:types = @{
"double" = "DOUBLE PRECISION"; 
"int" = "INTEGER"; 
"QString" = "INTEGER";
"Ignored" = "1";
"Normal" = "2";
"Critical" = "3" }

function resultToSql($element)
{
  $global:sqlscript += ('"')
  $global:sqlscript += ($element.name + '" ')
  $global:sqlscript += ($global:types.Get_Item($element.type))
  $global:sqlscript += (',' + [Environment]::Newline)
  $global:sqlscript += ('"' + $element.name + "_metric_group" + " " + $global:types.Get_Item($element.metric_group.type))   
  $global:sqlscript += (',' + [Environment]::Newline)
}

function xmlToSql($source)
{
  Write-Host "Parsing...";
  $global:sqlscript += "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + '"' + $source.spec.task.ToLower() + '"'+ [Environment]::NewLine
  $global:sqlscript += '"' + "id" + '"' + " SERIAL NOT NULL" + [Environment]::NewLine

  foreach ($node in $source.spec.measure) {
      resultToSql $node
  }

  foreach ($m in $source.spec.error) {
    resultToSql $m
  }

  $global:sqlscript += '"' + "weighted_sum" + '" ' + $global:types.Get_Item("double") + [Environment]::Newline;
}

function main
{
  if ($directory -eq $null) { exit }
  else
  {
    $xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -include *Spec.xml
    foreach ($xmlfile in $xmlfiles)
    {
        Write-Host "Filename:" $xmlfile;
        [xml]$spec = Get-Content $file;
        xmlToSql $spec; 
        Write-Host $script;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised because main is not called in the script.

Comment: I've saved your posted script as `a.ps1`, and executed it with `a.ps1 "c:\temp"` (having added extra Write-Hosts for confirmation) and see no output on the console (i.e. no functions were called). Please can you clarify how you are executing this script?

Comment: I'm calling it from the Powershell ISE commandline ".\script.ps1 C:\path\to\specxmls\" without the quotes. This is a shot in the dark, but does powershell somehow cache scripts? I'm getting weird behaviour that almost seems like it doesn't register changes to the script. And even running it without an argument produces output that seems to be from an earlier execution.

Comment: Behaviour seems to be rectified by NOT using the 64 bit versions of ISE or shell.

Comment: For the record, the original question remains unanswered. Functions still produce output just from defining them.

Comment: @averagejoe No, functions don't produce "execution" output until they are invoked.  You may be confusing how ISE executes script by spitting it out to the output pane - which isn't actual output.  It's simulating how you would type in the function at an interactive prompt.

Comment: @Kieth Hill Okay. While I don't quite see the point of that, I guess I'll just have to take it at face value. I wound up unwinding the enter thing and just making one long loop with no functions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a C/C++/C# program, "you" need to call the `Main` function - at the bottom of this script. When you run the script above all it does is create the functions you've defined.  It doesn't run any of them.  You have to do that by calling them in the script and one of those calls has to be at the script level (outside any functions).

Comment: Judged as answer, coupled with Keith Hill's comment about ISE "simulating function output"(see his comment on the initial question)

Comment: Minor correction on that: @Keith's comment was that it is simulating **input**, not **output**.

Comment: @msorens Yes, that's what I meant (input).  Thanks for pointing out the correction.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell cant magically detect changes to scripts, close the ISE and re-open it then run your script again. If that fails take the contents of your script paste it in the ISE and click the execute button, i just did that and main didnt run.

Comment: I am trying to understand when powershell does or does not detect changes. I think that when it comes to main scripts, everything works ok. If you happen to use a function on the same file and change something in this functions ISE requires a restart. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the main function container so it resembles the code below:

```
  if ($directory -eq $null) { exit }
  else
  {
    $xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -include *Spec.xml
    foreach ($xmlfile in $xmlfiles)
    {
        Write-Host "Filename:" $xmlfile;
        [xml]$spec = Get-Content $file;
        xmlToSql $spec; 
        Write-Host $script;
    }
  }
```

Powershell doesn't execute from Main like C#/C++. It executes what statements are first received outside functions. In this case above it will execute the if statement first as it appears outside the function box.